# problems filtering XMLListCollection

Tags: apache-flex, filtering, flash-builder4.5

I'm trying to create some sort of rangking. For this, I'm using a multilevel xml which I create with a php file.

```
<klassement>    
      <reeks>
         <reeksId>1</reeksId>
         <reeksNaam>3de klasse</reeksNaam>
         <ploeg>
            <ploegNaam>Foo</ploegNaam>
            <goalsMade>60</goalsMade>
            <points>12</points>
         </ploeg>
         <ploeg>
            <ploegNaam>bar</ploegNaam>
            <goalsMade>10</goalsMade>
            <points>2</points>
         </ploeg>    
      </reeks>    
      <reeks>
         <reeksId>2</reeksId>
         <reeksNaam>3de klasse res</reeksNaam>
         <ploeg>
            <ploegNaam>Foo res</ploegNaam>
            <goalsMade>50</goalsMade>
            <points>12</points>
         </ploeg>
         <ploeg>
            <ploegNaam>bar</ploegNaam>
            <goalsMade>40</goalsMade>
            <points>8</points>
         </ploeg>    
       </reeks> 
</klassement>
```

And so on, and so on (you get the point) I get the information with httpService in my application. Afterwards I'm putting that information in an XMLListCollection. Now I'm trying to seperate the levels (probably not the right way, but it works). When I debug I can see that those 2 new vars have the right stuff in it, but when I when I say the dataProvider of the datagrid has to be klassementKern I'm getting the error "implicit coercion of a value of type XML to an unrelated type mx.collections:IList"

Does someone know why this is and how I can fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    height="600"
                    skinClass="skins.ListContainerSkin"
                    creationComplete="httpKlassement.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="httpKlassement"
                       url="http://localhost/flexScripts/klassement.php"
                       resultFormat="e4x"
                       result="showKlassement(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var klassement:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementKern:XML;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementReserve:XML;


            protected function showKlassement(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                klassement = new XMLListCollection(event.result.reeks);
                klassementKern = klassement[0]; 
                klassementReserve = klassement[1];
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:DataGrid width="760" height="230" dataProvider="{klassementKern}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Ploeg" dataField="ploeg.ploegNaam"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="WG" dataField="ploeg.aantalGespeeld"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="W" dataField="ploeg.aantalGewonnen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="V" dataField="ploeg.aantalVerloren"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="G" dataField="ploeg.aantalGelijk"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D+" dataField="ploeg.goalenGemaakt"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D-" dataField="ploeg.goalenTegen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Punten" dataField="ploeg.punten"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="DS" dataField="ploeg.doelpuntensaldo"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:NavigatorContent>
```

Comment: Entschuldi, mein Niederländisch ist nicht so gut...

Comment: Tried by creating a file data.xml with xml you have provided. Its working, no errors. Please confirm that klassement.php is giving the right xml, you can check the server response in firebug.

Comment: When I open the php script in chrome it gives me the right xml structure, when I debug in flash builder klassement, klassementKern and klassementReserve is filled with the right information, but I don't get the information in the datagrid. I've put it online this afternoon. The link to the php file is http://www.dehertoghnathalie2011.dreamhosters.com/flexScripts/klassement.php (the domain name was for something else, but we had to drop the php files into the same account, new folder). Right now I solved it by hardcoding the datagrids and title, but it would be better with httpsService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I'll post my new code below in case someone else has the same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    creationComplete="httpKlassement.send()" 
                    xmlns:components="components.*">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="httpKlassement"
                       url="http://www.dehertoghnathalie2011.dreamhosters.com/flexScripts/klassement.php"
                       result="showKlassement(event)"
                       fault="httpKlassement_faultHandler(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.IList;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var klassement:ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementKern:Object;
            [Bindable]
            private var kern:IList;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementReserve:Object;
            [Bindable]
            private var reserve:IList;


            protected function showKlassement(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                klassement = event.result.klassement.reeks;
                klassementKern = klassement[0]; 
                kern = klassementKern.ploeg;
                klassementReserve = klassement[1];  
                reserve = klassementReserve.ploeg;
            }

            protected function httpKlassement_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(event.fault.faultString, "Foutmelding");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="0" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:DataGrid width="760" height="235" dataProvider="{kern}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>         
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Ploeg" dataField="ploegNaam"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="WG" dataField="aantalGespeeld"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="W" dataField="aantalGewonnen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="V" dataField="aantalVerloren"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="G" dataField="aantalGelijk"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D+" dataField="goalenGemaakt"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D-" dataField="goalenTegen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Punten" dataField="punten"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="DS" dataField="doelpuntensaldo"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>

    <s:DataGrid width="760" height="235" dataProvider="{reserve}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>         
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Ploeg" dataField="ploegNaam"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="WG" dataField="aantalGespeeld"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="W" dataField="aantalGewonnen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="V" dataField="aantalVerloren"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="G" dataField="aantalGelijk"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D+" dataField="goalenGemaakt"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D-" dataField="goalenTegen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Punten" dataField="punten"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="DS" dataField="doelpuntensaldo"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:NavigatorContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with harcoded XML constant, so you're probably get something else from the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
    creationComplete="showKlassement(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private const MY_XML:XML =
                <klassement>    
                      <reeks>
                         <reeksId>1</reeksId>
                         <reeksNaam>3de klasse</reeksNaam>
                         <ploeg>
                            <ploegNaam>Foo</ploegNaam>
                            <goalsMade>60</goalsMade>
                            <points>12</points>
                         </ploeg>
                         <ploeg>
                            <ploegNaam>bar</ploegNaam>
                            <goalsMade>10</goalsMade>
                            <points>2</points>
                         </ploeg>    
                      </reeks>    
                      <reeks>
                         <reeksId>2</reeksId>
                         <reeksNaam>3de klasse res</reeksNaam>
                         <ploeg>
                            <ploegNaam>Foo res</ploegNaam>
                            <goalsMade>50</goalsMade>
                            <points>12</points>
                         </ploeg>
                         <ploeg>
                            <ploegNaam>bar</ploegNaam>
                            <goalsMade>40</goalsMade>
                            <points>8</points>
                         </ploeg>    
                       </reeks> 
                </klassement>;                  

            [Bindable]
            private var klassement:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementKern:XML;
            [Bindable]
            private var klassementReserve:XML;

            private function showKlassement(event:FlexEvent):void   {
                klassement = new XMLListCollection(MY_XML.reeks);
                klassementKern = klassement[0]; 
                klassementReserve = klassement[1];
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:DataGrid width="760" height="230" dataProvider="{klassement}">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Ploeg" dataField="ploeg.ploegNaam"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="WG" dataField="ploeg.aantalGespeeld"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="W" dataField="ploeg.aantalGewonnen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="V" dataField="ploeg.aantalVerloren"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="G" dataField="ploeg.aantalGelijk"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D+" dataField="ploeg.goalenGemaakt"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="D-" dataField="ploeg.goalenTegen"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="Punten" dataField="ploeg.punten"/>
                <s:GridColumn headerText="DS" dataField="ploeg.doelpuntensaldo"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: but don't you get just one datagrid? I need 2, one for 'Kern' and one for 'Reserve'. And why would it show the data if you hardcode it, and not when I use an httpService? I find that weird :) (or is that because I'm new at this =D)

Comment: Maybe because httpService delivers something else, like an error text?

Comment: No httpService gives me the right information. The link to the php file (which creates the xml is written in the comment above). When I debug it I can see the right information in all the variables